# How To Raise Property Changed events on a Dependency Property?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a control with two properties. One is a `DependencyProperty`, the other is an "alias" to the first one.  How do I raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the second one (the alias) when the first one is changed.

**NOTE**: I'm using `DependencyObjects`, not `INotifyPropertyChanged` (tried that, didn't work because my control is a `ListVie` sub-classed)

Something like this.....

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    if (e.Property == MyFirstProperty)
    {
        RaiseAnEvent( MySecondProperty ); /// what is the code that would go here?
    }    
}
```

If I were using an INotify I could do like this...

```
public string SecondProperty
{
    get
    {
        return this.m_IconPath;
    }
}

public string IconPath
{
    get
    {
        return this.m_IconPath;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this.m_IconPath != value)
        {
            this.m_IconPath = value;
        this.SendPropertyChanged("IconPath");
        this.SendPropertyChanged("SecondProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

Where can I raise `PropertyChanged` events on multiple properties from one setter?  I need to be able to do the same thing, only using `DependencyProperties`.

Comment: If you're not using INotifyPropertyChanged, then there is no PropertyChanged event to raise (unless you're talking about a custom event?).  Also, I wasn't sure whether the "alias" property is a DP or a plain CLR property -- could you clarify?  Thanks!

Comment: the "alias" is not a DP, but I want it to act like one. so that when the first property is changed my UI will be notified that the other one has changed.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

1. Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your class.
2. Specify a callback in the property metadata when you register the dependency property.
3. In the callback, raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

Adding the callback:

```
public static DependencyProperty FirstProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "First", 
  typeof(string), 
  typeof(MyType),
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
     false, 
     new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFirstPropertyChanged)));
```

Raising `PropertyChanged` in the callback:

```
private static void OnFirstPropertyChanged(
   DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   PropertyChangedEventHandler h = PropertyChanged;
   if (h != null)
   {
      h(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Second"));
   }
}
```

Comment: first is already a dp, inherited from my base class (ListView) and im catching the property change in OnPropertyChanged. I will try this, and see what we get.

Comment: How are you obtaining a reference to the `PropertyChanged` event from within the static method? You would first need to cast to `INotifyPropertyChanged` and access the event there.

Comment: Your answer does not work since you are trying to access a non-static member through a static method. You should edit your answer as @BrettRyan states.

Comment: How can you call propertychanged in static method?

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. It appears that if an object is a `DependencyObject`, the WPF engine ignores `INotifyPropertyChanged` and doesn't subscribe to its event.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it as a solution as "PropertyChanged" event can't be accessed within static method.

Answer (score 80):

I ran into a similar problem where I have a dependency property that I wanted the class to listen to change events to grab related data from a service.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomerProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Customer", typeof(Customer),
        typeof(CustomerDetailView),
        new PropertyMetadata(OnCustomerChangedCallBack));

public Customer Customer {
    get { return (Customer)GetValue(CustomerProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CustomerProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnCustomerChangedCallBack(
        DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CustomerDetailView c = sender as CustomerDetailView;
    if (c != null) {
        c.OnCustomerChanged();
    }
}

protected virtual void OnCustomerChanged() {
    // Grab related data.
    // Raises INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    OnPropertyChanged("Customer");
}
```

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but this answer solved my doubts like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Couple months late - but this worked like a charm. I've been trying to crack this for a while now. Thanks!

Comment: This seems more appropriate than the accepted answer.

Comment: This works to allow a `Label` to have an `IsSelected` property (like `TreeViewItem` behavior) to change the background color. Perfect.

Comment: I know I'm way late, but I just came across this when googling ist, others might as well. I like this approach, but you can inline the Callback the reduce overhead like this:

new PropertyMetadata((o,e) => (o as Customer)?.OnCustomerChanged()));

Answer (score 11):

I think the OP is asking the wrong question. The code below will show that it not necessary to manually raise the `PropertyChanged` EVENT from a dependency property to achieve the desired result. The way to do it is handle the `PropertyChanged` CALLBACK on the dependency property and set values for other dependency properties there. The following is a working example.
In the code below, `MyControl` has two dependency properties - `ActiveTabInt` and `ActiveTabString`. When the user clicks the button on the host (`MainWindow`), `ActiveTabString` is modified. The `PropertyChanged` CALLBACK on the dependency property sets the value of `ActiveTabInt`. The `PropertyChanged` EVENT is not manually raised by `MyControl`.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        ActiveTabString = "zero";
    }

    private string _ActiveTabString;
    public string ActiveTabString
    {
        get { return _ActiveTabString; }
        set
        {
            if (_ActiveTabString != value)
            {
                _ActiveTabString = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ActiveTabString");
            }
        }
    }

    private int _ActiveTabInt;
    public int ActiveTabInt
    {
        get { return _ActiveTabInt; }
        set
        {
            if (_ActiveTabInt != value)
            {
                _ActiveTabInt = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ActiveTabInt");
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveTabString = (ActiveTabString == "zero") ? "one" : "zero";
    }

}

public class MyControl : Control
{
    public static List<string> Indexmap = new List<string>(new string[] { "zero", "one" });


    public string ActiveTabString
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ActiveTabStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ActiveTabStringProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveTabStringProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ActiveTabString",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            null,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
            ActiveTabStringChanged));


    public int ActiveTabInt
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ActiveTabIntProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ActiveTabIntProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveTabIntProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ActiveTabInt",
        typeof(Int32),
        typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            new Int32(),
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));


    static MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));

    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }


    private static void ActiveTabStringChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyControl thiscontrol = sender as MyControl;

        if (Indexmap[thiscontrol.ActiveTabInt] != thiscontrol.ActiveTabString)
            thiscontrol.ActiveTabInt = Indexmap.IndexOf(e.NewValue.ToString());

    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Button Content="Change Tab Index" Click="Button_Click" Width="110" Height="30"></Button>
    <local:MyControl x:Name="myControl" ActiveTabInt="{Binding ActiveTabInt, Mode=TwoWay}" ActiveTabString="{Binding ActiveTabString}"></local:MyControl>
</StackPanel>
```

App.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyControl">
                    <TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding ActiveTabInt, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <TabItem Header="Tab Zero">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActiveTabInt}"></TextBlock>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="Tab One">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActiveTabInt}"></TextBlock>
                        </TabItem>
                    </TabControl>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I had a quirk with this, I could not find ``RaisePropertyChanged(`` but instead had to use ``RaisePropertyChangedEventImmediately(``

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Sam and Xaser and have actually taken this a bit farther. I don't think you should be implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in a `UserControl` at all...the control is already a `DependencyObject` and therefore already comes with notifications. Adding `INotifyPropertyChanged` to a `DependencyObject` is redundant and "smells" wrong to me.

What I did is implement both properties as `DependencyProperties`, as Sam suggests, but then simply had the `PropertyChangedCallback` from the "first" dependency property alter the value of the "second" dependency property. Since both are dependency properties, both will automatically raise change notifications to any interested subscribers (e.g. data binding etc.)

In this case, dependency property A is the string `InviteText`, which triggers a change in dependency property B, the `Visibility` property named `ShowInvite`. This would be a common use case if you have some text that you want to be able to hide completely in a control via data binding.

```
public string InviteText  
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(InviteTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(InviteTextProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty InviteTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("InviteText", typeof(string), typeof(InvitePrompt), new UIPropertyMetadata(String.Empty, OnInviteTextChanged));

private static void OnInviteTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    InvitePrompt prompt = d as InvitePrompt;
    if (prompt != null)
    {
        string text = e.NewValue as String;
        prompt.ShowInvite = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }
}

public Visibility ShowInvite
{
    get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ShowInviteProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ShowInviteProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowInviteProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ShowInvite", typeof(Visibility), typeof(InvitePrompt), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Collapsed));
```

Note I'm not including the `UserControl` signature or constructor here because there is nothing special about them; they don't need to subclass from `INotifyPropertyChanged` at all.

Comment: I agree with you that it doesn't make sense to use INPC. Your example behaves differently than the OP's example though.  Yours creates duplicate data that can become out of sync: `ShowInvite` is publicly changeable, but doesn't update `InviteText`. OP's `SecondProperty` is read-only.  `ShowInvite` should be a read-only DependencyProperty.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon the previous accepted answer, for me the cast was missing to get access to the non-static `PropertyChanged`:

1. Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your class, e.g. `UserControl CustomView`
2. Specify a callback in the property metadata when you register the
   dependency property.
3. In the callback, cast and raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

Adding the callback:

```
public static DependencyProperty FirstProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "First", 
  typeof(string), 
  typeof(MyType),
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
     false, 
     new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFirstPropertyChanged)));
```

Cast the sender and raise PropertyChanged in the callback:

```
private static void OnFirstPropertyChanged(
   DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var control = (CustomView)sender;
   PropertyChangedEventHandler h = control.PropertyChanged;
   if (h != null)
   {
      h(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Second"));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I question the logic of raising a `PropertyChanged` event on the second property when it's the first property that's changing.  If the second properties value changes then the `PropertyChanged` event could be raised there.

At any rate, the answer to your question is you should implement `INotifyPropertyChange`. This interface contains the `PropertyChanged` event. Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` lets other code know that the class has the `PropertyChanged` event, so that code can hook up a handler. After implementing `INotifyPropertyChange`, the code that goes in the if statement of your `OnPropertyChanged` is:

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
    PropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MySecondProperty"));
```

Comment: I am deriving from the ListView control. I can add INotify, and, in fact, i tried that. no dice, when i tried to raise the event, nothing happened.  the property i want to "alais" is a dependency property.