# What is the best way to notify a parent that a WPF User Control Dependency Property has changed?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding

I am building a WPF User Control in VB.net. This control is bound to a dependency property in the xaml.vb code behind.

There is no ViewModel.

This is a control that is intended to be used by dropping it on other WPF forms.  What is the best approach to raise an event when the dependency property changes.

Do I need to make the code behind implement INotifyPropertyChanged or simply raise a custom event?

I guess I'm really asking about best practices.

Comment: Perhaps this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480366/how-to-raise-property-changed-events-on-a-dependency-property?rq=1) is going to help you.

Comment: Sorry - what is an SO Post?

Comment: SO = stackoverflow ;o)