# How to change row background color in DataGrid (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I need to paint some row in DataGrid in some color.

I have created collection in main UI Thread:

```
ObservableCollection<SomeElement> col= new ObservableCollection<SomeElement> ();
```

Then I change it from other thread:

```
int someElementNumber = 1;
int someInputValue = 11;
col[someElementNumber].SomePropery = someInputValue;
```

I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface on `SomeElement` so that my `DataGrid` update value in that row. But I want to check this value and depend on it print row in some background color:

```
if (someInputValue > 10) {
    //paint row in some color
}
```

Please give me advice how to do it. Thanks everybody for helping in advance!

Comment: In wpf you are not using `Changing/Changed` validation pattern. There are bindings and corresponding properties setters to validate instead (see [Binding validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.110).aspx)). Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I need to update some property of element and depend on value paint row in some background color.

Comment: Why don't you add what you have tried

Comment: I added, ask your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer by myself. If somebody interest:

1) Make `Binding` with `DataTrigger` on `CheckProperty` in XAML. That property is not necessary to be visible.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CheckProperty}" Value="Success">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CheckProperty}" Value="Error">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

2) In thread, that update `Collection col` set `CheckProperty` some value depend on some condition.

```
int someElementNumber = 1;
int someInputValue = 11;
col[someElementNumber].SomePropery = someInputValue;
if (someInputValue > 10) {
    col[someElementNumber].CheckProperty = "Success";
}
else {
    col[someElementNumber].CheckProperty = "Error";
}
```

`CheckProperty` has to [Rise Property changed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480366/how-to-raise-property-changed-events-on-a-dependency-property)!

When that property just have been updated, `DataTrigger` will be invoked and it print current row in some background color depend on condition.