# Propagate DependencyProperty default value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I've an WPF UserControl with a ViewModel:

```
<MyUserControl ...>
    <Grid Name="UxRootContainer">
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <MyViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
    </Grid>
</MyUserControl>
```

This UserControl has a DependencyProperty, that has to be propagated to the ViewModel:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DurationProperty = 
     DependencyProperty.Register( "Duration", typeof(TimeSpan),
     typeof(MyUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(TimeSpan.FromHour(1), OnDurationChanged ));

public TimeSpan Duration
{
    get { return (TimeSpan)GetValue(DurationProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DurationProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnDurationChanged(DependencyObject source, 
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyUserControl control = source as MyUserControl;
    TimeSpan duration = (TimeSpan)e.NewValue;
    control.UxRootContainer.SetDuration(duration);
}
```

This is working fine, except we will not receive the default value in the `OnDurationChanged` event.

I know I could call to this method myself in the constructor, put the default duration into a constant, but:

- I've to create a constant for every DependencyProperty
- I will have to call this even if at the end I don't use the default value

Any nice proposal on how to propagate the default value to the ViewModel, only if the default value is the one used at the end(not other value set).

Comment: It's not really MVVM. Creating ViewModel in the View is generally bad idea (might be ok for main window). The point is what `UserControl` are often datatemplates of `ViewModel` (this means what you will have `ViewModel` somewhere, but your control can't be used as a datatemplate, because it set its `DataContext` explicitly). Following that you should do it opposite: `View` takes value from `ViewModel` (whenever it's default value or a new one). Which can be done in `Loaded` event (you will get this event 100%).

Comment: @Sinatr It's a little bit offtopic, but I'm sorry but I disagree, MVVM can be view first or ViewModel first. For the views, we use Prism ViewModelLocator to get the ViewModel. In this case, this is not really a "View", this is really a UserControl that will be usable in a lot of different context in the application. Don't you think that it would be weird if your TextBlock has to find itself what field it has to display ? ;)

Comment: @Sinatr I've a "ViewModel" behind only to have my internal bindable properties. I agree that maybe the name is not the best, but it contains the same logic than a real ViewModel(commands, INotifyPropertyChange implementation, ...)

Comment: *"Don't you think that it would be weird if your TextBlock has to find itself what field it has to display"* - no. Binding already makes View element un-aware about anything. `TextBlock` has no idea what it will display at the end. If you create 2 ViewModel instances, they could have different value for same View to display. Therefore don't get value from the view. View should get value from ViewModel.

Comment: @Sinatr Nope. Like I said, this UserControl is being to be used inside a lot of different Views, which already have their ViewModel. To be more concrete, my UserControl has just a collection of Point, and a duration(which is the number of points to display). It doesn't know where the points comes from, this will totally depends in which view this will be used. Same as the TextBlock.

Comment: I see what you mean, but then it doesn't make any sense to separate logic from the View. Why would you create ViewModel for that control at all? And without having it ... you don't need to pass anything, right? E.g. my custom controls (which I use in other View as *controls*) don't have ViewModel (it doesn't make sense to make one, because they will never be separated, e.g. no other View will be re-using same ViewModel). That's because controls do not have underlying Model to abstract from. Moreover, don't set this control `DataContext`, you may run into troubles of bindings to that control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> except we will not receive the default value in the OnDurationChanged event

Have the class adhere to `INotifyPropertyChanged` and then have the VM (or whatever needs the info) subscribe to the event off of the control. That way when it changes (or it the value is set) the consumer is notified.

See this SO answer to this question [How To Raise Property Changed events on a Dependency Property?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2482402/285795)

> Any nice proposal on how to propagate the default value to the ViewModel, only if the default value is the one used at the end(not other value set).

You describe business logic which would need to be coded to determine whether the default value is being used. It doesn't appear that without said logic, your request could be accomplished.

---

What is happening is a race condition. A control cannot be bound for notify changes to something that does not exist...the creation of the control happens first, the default value is set second, then your control binds to it, all at runtime of course. The operation is set in place at design time, but that does not affect the process per-se.

Comment: My issue is not that my ViewModel value is not propagated to the UserControl, but quite the opposite, the default of my DependencyProperty is not given to the UserControl model(it's really a UserControl, not just  a "view".

Comment: @J4N What is happening is a *race* condition. A control cannot be bound for notify changes to something that does not exist...the creation of the control happens first, the default value is set second, then your control binds to it, all at runtime of course. The operation is set in place at design time, but that does not affect the process per-se.

Comment: I understand, but what would be a nice workaround? Is there a way to indicate to the DP that we want to be registered before it assigns the default value?

Answer (score 3):

I decide to write an answer (to see down-votes in case I am wrong :).

In given case you are creating *custom control*, which is meant to be a simple control inside other Views. Two points:

- do not create ViewModel;
- do not set `DataContext` of this control.

ViewModel doesn't serve any purpose in this case: there is no underlying Model to abstract from, nothing (not View, nor ViewModel) will be reused. Without ViewModel existence default value is already default value of dependence property = problem solved.

As for `DataContext`: if you try to use this control inside list to bind item property to it you will always have to refer to it via parent container `DataContext` (because control has its overriden and binding `"{Binding Text}"` will not refer to that item `Text` property, but to a control ViewModel Text property, and you will have to do something like `"{Binding DataContext.Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}"`). That's not right in any design.

Comment: You understood correctly, but here is why I've a ViewModel(or a Model): 1. From the values I get from the dependency property, I've to compute several others. So having a Model allows me to set the value from the dependency property, and directly compute all the others values that will be bound inside my userControl. 2. It allows me to Unit Tests easily all the logic behind: if the user bind me something to my DependencyProperty, I can check that I've the expected result in my computed fields. Regarding the `DataContext`, I don't set it on the Control, but its grid.

Comment: Also, I agree, this on the design a "CustomControl", but I didn't explained it like this because I was thinking that a CustomControl has no XAML, only styles that applies to it, no? Which is not my case.

Comment: I don't believe that a custom control needs a view model, only pages. +1