# Using a dependency property with a view model to change the Fill of a Rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, dependency-properties

I have View with a Rectangle and depending on a boolean variable I want to set the Fill to a specific brush. For this I have added a DependencyProperty to the ViewModel.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FalseColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "FalseColor",
            typeof(Brush),
            typeof(BooleanRectangleView),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Application.Current.FindResource("LightGreyBrush"), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

public Brush FalseColor
{
    get { return (Brush)GetValue(FalseColorProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FalseColorProperty, value); }
}
```

In the View, I added a style to the rectangle with the following Trigger

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.Model.Variable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding DataContext.FalseColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Since I have the DependencyProperty in the ViewModel, I don't know how to set it when creating the UserControl. For example, the following does not work

```
<BooleanRectangleView FalseColor="..."/>
```

Also, when I am running the program, I get an exception in the constructor of the ViewModel:

> The default type does not match the type of the property `FalseColor` (translated from German)

**EDIT:**

When I cast the FindResource to Brush I get a new exception:

> The default value for the property `FalseColor` cannot be bound to a specific thread

I guess that has something to do with FindResource not necessarily being called from the dispatcher thread?

Comment: If you put a DP in a ViewModel class this class will be a DependencyObject. You don't want that. You only need a Property that raises INotifyPropertyChanged. You probably made a mistake writing it, it's probably in your View class. About your issue: You need to set the FalseColor in the Style and in the DataTrigger. On your default value issue: you need to cast the FindResource to Brush

Comment: @nkoniishvt: Can you explain why I don't want a ViewModel to be a DependencyObject?

Comment: None of the reasons for having a dependency property (usually) applies to view model properties. You don't want a view model property to be the target of a binding, or be set in a style setter, or be animated, etc.

Comment: The ViewModel layer is supposed to provide data for View to display and permit the View layer to update data in the Model layer. Being a DependencyObject means it is a view element and have lot of overhead that's not useful for a ViewModel layer (Dispatcher, Animation of properties for example, it's useless for a ViewModel class)

Comment: @nkoniishvt: Okay, I get that, but then I have the problem that I have two data contexts. One for the ViewModel and one for the DependencyProperty. How does that work?

Comment: @Clemens: Yes, the boolean variable I am binding to is in my Model, not in my ViewModel.

Comment: Given that the DataContext of your control references the view model instance (and that the view model has a `Model` property that actually references the model instance), your DataTrigger Binding would just be `{Binding Model.Variable}`. In the Setter of the DataTrigger you could directly access the Brush resource. Of course the model would have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Otherwise move the property to the view model, or wrap it in the view model.

Comment: @Clemens: I don't want to directly access a specific Brush resource, I want it as a DependencyProperty so that I can specify it when creating the UserControl.

Comment: Than declare the dependency property in the UserControl.

Comment: It's ok to have DP for `UserControl`. You may don't need to have ViewModel then. Think what your control does, is it a *one possible* view of whatever model you have (means will you *reuse* ViewModel) or is it rather a *custom control*. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37324744/1997232) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your structure here: You tell that FalseColorProperty is in the ViewModel layer but the class is called BooleanRectangleView which should probably be a name for a View class (UserControl or something like that).

In your case you'll have this DP in your View in addition to a bool named IsVariableTrue for example.

In your ViewModel you'll have the Variable property which makes the Variable property from your Model accessible.

In the BooleanRectangleView XAMl you'll have a Style:

```
<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Fill}"/> <!-- Binding to the Rectangle Fill property -->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Property="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type BooleanRectangleView}}, Path=IsVariableTrue}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type BooleanRectangleView}}, Path=FalseColor}"/> <!-- Binding to the DP in the View -->
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
    ...
</Rectangle>
```

In the XAML that uses your BooleanRectangleView:

```
<BooleanRectangleView IsVariableTrue="{Binding Variable}"/> <!-- Binding to the ViewModel -->
```

On Your DP declaration:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FalseColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "FalseColor",
    typeof(Brush),
    typeof(BooleanRectangleView),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        Brush.Red, 
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender
    )
);

public Brush FalseColor
{
    get { return (Brush)GetValue(FalseColorProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FalseColorProperty, value); }
}
```

You'll want to set the DP value in the constructor of your BooleanRectangleView:

```
public BooleanRectangleView() {

    InitializeComponents();
    FalseColor = (Brush)Application.Current.FindResource("Infoteam_LightGreyBrush");
}
```

I'm sure there's a better solution but it should work fine.

*Edited*

Replaced the TemplateBinding for a Binding with RelativeSource as we're not in a ControlTemplate.
Replaced the Trigger with a DataTrigger because the IsVariableTrue doesn't exist in a Rectangle.

Comment: Just to get it right, where do I put the DP declaration? In the View?

Comment: I get the errors `FalseColor member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name` and `The member FalseColor is not recognized or is not accessible` on `Value="{TemplateBinding FalseColor}"`.

Comment: @gartenriese and yes, DP declarations should be in the code-behind of the view

Comment: Edited a couple of things that wouldn't have worked (didn't test the code)