# c# - localization - changing language in wpf app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am making some wpf application and I need option for changing languages. I have folder named Resorces in my solution, where I store all my resx file - actually language.resx and language.en-EN.resx. My XAML looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="CoinCatalogue.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CoinCatalogue"
    xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:CoinCatalogue.Resources"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="{x:Static resx:language.WindowName}" Height="480" Width="640">
<Grid>
    <Menu x:Name="menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517">
        <MenuItem x:Name="File" Header="{x:Static resx:language.File}">
            <MenuItem x:Name="Open" Header="{x:Static resx:language.Open}"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

</Grid>
```

Everything is ok - I have access to string in app. And in my main class I am trying to change culture with line:

```
language.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-EN");
```

But nothings happen to my app. This line is before  InitializeComponent();.

What am I doing wrong? I am using Visual Studio 2015. /is it a good idea to change app language in this way?

Comment: How does your program know that the language is changing? Whenever you change something that is displayed in a WPF application, you need to let your presentation know by calling OnPropertyChanged(). You do this with text and controls to let your application know that something needs to be updated. If you are changing out the resource that holds information to display to the user, you most likely need to call OnPropertyChange for all the text that should be updated.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onpropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I was basing on tutorials like this: https://robertoschiabel.wordpress.com/2010/01/31/wpf-add-localization-via-resx-files/. All controls (theirs labels) need to be changed via OnPropertChanged? Now it is changed via new compilation, but all in all it would have checkable option in menu.

Comment: Yes. That tutorial is also setting the language when the app starts up. So if you set it there, you will have rebuild your app every time it changes. You might want to spend some time getting acquainted with the MVVM paradigm. 

Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480366/how-to-raise-property-changed-events-on-a-dependency-property

Answer (score 1):

I think how you are changing the culture is the issue.

I just put a quick sample together where I had the following resx files:

> Resources.en-US.resx
>
> Resources.fr-FR.resx
>
> Resources.resx

If I run the app without attempting to change the culture, I get the strings from the `Resources.en-US.resx` file as that is my default. If I add this code before `InitializeComponent` my strings come from the `Resources.fr-FR.resx` file:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

Comment: In this way I could change language on run-time? For ex. I click button and after it app is refreshed and is in selected language?

Comment: No, if you want to do this at runtime, I would suggest an implementation something like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22967/WPF-Runtime-Localization

Comment: Ok. I will try it. I have also try to change culture in your way - nothing happens. But I figured out that problem is name of the culture. It is not working with ex. "fr-FR' but it is working with "FR" (anything without dash in name). Weird...