# Accessing .xaml items from different .xaml.cs file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have .xaml items accross three files. In one .xaml I have option to change language at running.

Is there any chance how can I access items from others .xaml to change the language as well?

Changing language of .xaml items in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string strLanguage = "";
    Boolean boolInit = true;

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Set_Language();
    }

    private void ddlLanguage_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Set_Language();
    }

    private void Set_Language()
    {
        if (boolInit == false)
        {
            strLanguage = "SMS_Vrana.Languages." + ((ComboBoxItem)ddlLanguage.SelectedItem).Name.ToString();
            ResourceManager LocRM = new ResourceManager(strLanguage, typeof(MainWindow).Assembly);
            lblNumber.Text = LocRM.GetString("strNumber");
            lblMessage.Text = LocRM.GetString("strMessage");
            btnSend.Content = LocRM.GetString("strSend");
            menuItemFile.Header = LocRM.GetString("strMenuFile");
            menuItemMainMenu.Header = LocRM.GetString("strMenuMainMenu");
            menuItemClose.Header = LocRM.GetString("strMenuClose");
            menuItemCheckConnection.Header = LocRM.GetString("strMenuConnection");

        }
    }
```

.xaml of Mainwindow.xaml:

```
<grid>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,434">
        <MenuItem Header="_File" Name="menuItemFile">
            <MenuItem Header="_Main Menu" Click="MenuItem_Click" Name="menuItemMainMenu"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Close" Click="MenuItem_Close" Name="menuItemClose"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Monitoring" IsEnabled="False">
            <MenuItem Header="Ping" IsCheckable="True" Checked="menuPingCheck" Unchecked="menuPingUncheck"/>
            <MenuItem Header="GSM" IsCheckable="True" Checked="menuGsmCheck" Unchecked="menuGsmUncheck"/>
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem Header="Check Connection" Click="menuItemCheckConnection_Click" Name="menuItemCheckConnection"/>

        <ComboBox x:Name="ddlLanguage" SelectionChanged="ddlLanguage_SelectionChanged" Height="23" Width="80">
            <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False" IsSelected="True" Content="Language"/>
            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="English" Content="English"/>
            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Czech" Content="Cesky"/>
        </ComboBox>

        <MenuItem Header="_Language" x:Name="menuLangTest" IsEnabled="True" Visibility="Hidden">
            <MenuItem Header="Czech" x:Name="menuCzech" Checked="menuItemCzechCheck" Unchecked="menuItemCzechUnche"/>
            <MenuItem Header="English" x:Name="menuEng" Checked="menuItemEngCheck" Unchecked="menuItemEngUnche"/>
        </MenuItem>


    </Menu>


    <Ellipse Fill="#000000" Stroke="#000000" Margin="10,0,0,347" x:Name="ellGSM" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="38" Height="38" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <Ellipse Fill="#000000" Stroke="#000000" Margin="204,0,0,347" Name="ellCol" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="38" Height="38" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtNumber" MaxLength="13" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310" Margin="10,153,0,0" PreviewTextInput="txtNumber_PreviewTextInput"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtMessage" MaxLength="1300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310" Margin="10,250,0,0"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnSend" Cursor="Hand" Content="Send!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310" Margin="10,407,0,0" Height="52" FontSize="36" Click="btnSend_Click"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Name="lblNumber" Text="Number" Margin="10,122,213,321"  FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="lblMessage" Text="Message" Margin="10,217,213,224" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="GSM" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="53,46,0,0" Name="txtblockGsm" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="PING" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="172,46,0,0" Name="txtblockPing" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="imgGsm" Height="42" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="49" Margin="271,40,0,0" Source="C:\Users\lvrabel\source\repos\SMS Vrána\SMS Vrána\Images\GsmGreen.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <Label Content="1300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="287,345,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Name="lblLeftCharacters" />
    <Label Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="280,84,0,0" Name="lblGsmSignal" Width="40"/>
   </grid>
```

.xaml of Authentication.xaml what I would like to access in MainWindow.xaml.cs for changing language for that items as well. I just would like to change language in whole application and no just for one window.

```
<Grid Margin="0,-17,0,0">

    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,17,0,432">
        <MenuItem Header="File" FontSize="16" Name="menuItemFile">
            <MenuItem Header="Back on Main Menu" Click="menuItemMainMenuClick"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Close" Click="menuItemCloseClick"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>



    <Label Content="IP Adress" Name="lblIPAddress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,210,0,0" Height="36" Width="101" FontSize="16"/>
    <Label Content="Login" Name="lblLogin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="31" Width="59" FontSize="16"/>
    <Label Content="Password" Name="lblPassword" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,343,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="31" Width="75" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="292" Margin="10,251,0,0" Name="txtBoxIP" PreviewTextInput="txtBoxIP_PreviewTextInput"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="292" Margin="10,315,0,0" Name="txtBoxLogin"/>
    <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="292" Margin="10,379,0,0" PasswordChar="*" Name="pswBox" Height="23" />
    <CheckBox Content="Remember me!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,413,0,0" Name="CheckBoxRemCredts" Checked="CheckBoxRemCredts_Checked"/>
    <Button Content="Login" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="10,442,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="292" Name="btnLoginAuth" Click="btnLoginAuth_Click" FontSize="18"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean @Dennis ? I have described my problem with I would like get help.

Comment: What he means is you haven't explained enough to help you. We know a "xaml" is somehow involved. That could be anything. A window a usercontrol, resource dictionary... What does "changing language" actually mean. The answer could be make whatever you are doing into a usercontrol and you can re-use it anywhere. Or it could be something else. Impossible to tell.

Comment: Ok, I though that you will understand. For example menuItem what is in Main.xaml. I need that menuItem to be accessable from Authentication.xaml.cs so I can change the menuitem.Header to another language. Changing language obv means that it changes language of items and all text/contents/headers to different Language using variables from .resx

Comment: @Cabry: we can't guess what you mean, sorry. :) Please, post relevant code.

Comment: My apology that I was unclear.

Comment: I think the solution would be use Bindings to read the strings from your LocRM object, and to share this object between both windows.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this properly without the sort of example that Dennis asked for. Please create a new project with just enough code to demonstrate the problem, and post the entire thing.

Comment: @RobinBennett I added whole .xaml's of both files + whole code for changing app language using .resx files.

Comment: Can you also post the C# and the code that launches the `Authentication` window please? That will be the key for passing data between the two forms.

Answer (score 1):

- U can access the `xaml` code of any `xaml` until and unless they are in same project and same solution.
- U just need to initialize the other xaml you want to use in your `xaml.cs` file.
- **For example,** I have two xaml files `Main.xaml` and `Login.xaml`
- So i can use Login view and its element in `Main.xaml.cs`
- **Syntax :**
  `Main.xaml.cs`

`Login login=new Login();`

- Now you can access any control of Login page provided u give name to every element you use.
- eg : `login.TextBlockEmail.Text="yourtext";`

**UPDATED ANSWER :**

Hi, I got what you are looking for. Your whole idea is to achieve Localization where all your views associated with the main view shall update.

There are multiple approaches to achieve this, here i am sharing links which may help you :

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22967/WPF-Runtime-Localization

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4a7f049b-f1b7-4982-874f-f9ecfe3d9140/how-to-change-the-language-in-my-view-wpf?forum=wpf

[c# - localization - changing language in wpf app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37793952/c-sharp-localization-changing-language-in-wpf-app)

Comment: Thank you for this. I can now access it like that. But when I change languge in MainWindow it won't change it in Authentication as well. Dont you have any idea?

Comment: Please check my updated Answer. I hope that shall help you out.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for is possible - surely you can get reference to some control in the backend file (.xaml.cs) and then assign it to some variable that is visible to both classes.

However this is better done by using events. You define some event on your main class that should be visible to every window, and then subscribe to it in the code for each window.